# How do we prove the "infinite propagation speed" property of the solution of the heat equation?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, parabolic-pde

Let $d\in\mathbb N$, $$p_t(x):=\left.\begin{cases}\frac{e^{-{\|x\|^2}{4|t|}}}{(4\pi|t|)^{\frac d2}}&\text{, if }t>0\\0&\text{, if }t<0\end{cases}\right\}\;\;\;\text{for }t\in\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}\text{ and }x\in\mathbb R^d$$ and $$p_t(x,y):=p_t(x-y)\;\;\;\text{for }t\in\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}\text{ and }x,y\in\mathbb R^d.$$

Moreover, let $\lambda$ denote the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$ and $$\kappa_t(x,B):=\int_Bp_t(x,y)\:\lambda^{\otimes d}({\rm d}y)\;\;\;\text{for }(x,B)\in\mathbb R^d\times\mathcal B(\mathbb R)^{\otimes d}$$ for $t\in\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$.

If $u_0\in C(\mathbb R^d)\cap\mathcal L^\infty(\mathbb R^d)$, we can easily see that $$u(t,x):=(\kappa_tu_0)(x)=\int\kappa_t(x,{\rm d}y)u_0(y)\;\;\;\text{for }(t,x)\in(0,\infty)\times\mathbb R^d$$ is a solution of the heat equation in $\mathbb R^d$, i.e. $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\Delta_xu\tag1.$$ Moreover, for all $x_0\in\mathbb R^d$, $$u(t,x)\xrightarrow{\begin{align}t&\to0+\\x&\to x_0\end{align}}u_0(x_0)\tag2.$$

> **Question 1**: I've read that "$u(t,x)$ depends on the values of $u_0(y)$ at all points $y\in\mathbb R^d$ no matter how far $y$ and $x$ are away" and "even when $u_0$ is compactly supported, tthe domain of influence on the solution $u$ is still all of $x\in\mathbb R^d$ as long as $t>0". What precisely does that mean and how do we prove this rigorously?

> **Question 2**: In light of $(2)$, are we able to extend $u$ to $[0,\infty)\times\Omega$ and show that $$u(0,x)=u_0(x)\tag3$$ for all $x\in\mathbb R^d$?

> **Question 3**: If we don't consider all of $\mathbb R^d$, but a bounded open subset $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ instead, is the solution of $$\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}=\Delta_xv\;\;\;\text{in }(0,\infty)\times\Omega\tag4$$ still of the previous form? And what would need to assume on $u_0:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ such that this solution satisfies $(3)$ for all $x\in\Omega$ as well?

Comment: (1) what is $q$? (2) what is $k_t (x, dy)$? Aren't you supposed to plug in a set instead of a measure in the second variable of $k_t$?

Comment: @ArcticChar (1) Sorry, removed that part. (2) $\kappa_t(x,\;\cdot\;)$ is a measure as defined in the question. $\kappa_t$ is a [transition kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition_kernel).

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment, but maybe not as thorough as an answer ought to be. I'll put it here regardless, hopefully it's useful :)

Regarding Q1, the best I can think of formalizing the statement is as follows: Suppose $u_0 \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d)$ (smooth functions which vanish identically outside of some ball) and suppose $u_0\geq 0$ throughout. Then you can easily check that $u$ as you construct it is always *positive* (this is because the kernel $p_t$ is strictly positive for positive times). The way to think about this is that no matter how localized your initial temperature $u_0$ is (remember it's zero outside of some ball), at any given time $t>0$, the solution $u(t,\cdot)>0$ throughout $\mathbb{R}^d$, so that even points very far from where $u_0$ was concentrated feel it's effect no matter how close $t$ is to $0$.

For Q2 the best I can say is yes, since you have convergence you can define $u(0,x)=u_0$ and the resulting function is continuous on $[0,\infty)\times \Omega$.

For Q3 the answer is no, not in general and the issue is a little delicate. It turns out, even in $\Omega=\mathbb{R}^d$, the way your question is written, the answer is no: There exist solutions to the heat equation that are not identically zero, but with zero initial data (these functions are wild, and they grow pretty fast as $|x|\to \infty$ for $t>0$). So the issue is that you needs to restrict what kind of solutions you're working with. One way of doing it is by looking at *bounded* solutions.

Of course, given the nature of the solutions I mentioned above, you can't expect the representation formula to be true in the bounded domain case either. But, if you impose some boundary conditions on $(0,\infty)\times\partial\Omega$, then you're closer to something. It turns out $p_t$ alone still won't give you the solution as before (your boundary conditions may not be satisfied), but it's not too bad. In this regard I'd suggest looking at Green's functions.